# How to build a nice Android-like user interface for my own application

Tags: android, user-interface, graphical-interaction

We are developing a software suite that heavily involves user interaction. We'd like to have a nice touch-based user interface, very similar to that of Android. Are there any libraries or other ways to easily build and use such user interfaces for own applications. We mainly develop in C++, but things in Python or Java or even something web-based would also help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to easily build graphical user interface for your Android Application, you can use DroidDraw http://www.droiddraw.org/

Also I would recommend Java programming language in combination with C++ language for your software application. DroidDraw has a plugin for Java programming language that would speed up your UI creation with ease :). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For web based, you can try GWT (Google Web Tookit) for java. Flex-AIR will be the another candidate for desktop application.